# How can I track my android device from a remote server?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm willing to create a personal system, which would keep track of my phone's location every ~5 minutes, and display it on a map on a website.
I'm trying to achieve this by having an (official) Google API that would let me know the location of my phone. (actually, 4 phones, which I would gather data for each of them)
I tried searching on what's existing, but I couldn't find anything, apart from stuff of 2013 that is no longer available.

Is there, to this day, any mean to achieve that, or do I need to create an application which would send data to a server from the phone?

Comment: `Google API that would let me know the location of my phone.` ? Google does not know the location of your phone. Your phone can know its location using gps.

Comment: @blackapps Google has it in multiple places, for example location history

Comment: Your phone will tell you the location. Why dont you use that? It has gps. It also knows the location if there is no internet available in the forest. Google only knows location if your phone just sent location to it. The phone knows it allways.

Comment: Yeah? But I want to be able to access that information from anywhere, not directly from my phone. For example, if I use my computer to go to my website, I'd like to be able to see where my phone on that website

Comment: So you are at home and your phone is travelling around.

Comment: I'm travelling and someone wants to know where am I, or I'm living normally and I want my server to keep track of where I'm going for further usage